# Woocommerce Search Results: include results from pages

Tags: php, wordpress, search, woocommerce

I’m working on a e-commerce using WordPress & Woocommerce. Currently, search results only display shop products. I would need search results to also display the results from other pages.

Is there a twist out there I can easily add to my functions.php?
Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: standard is that search will display both pages and products in a loop. Can you check if you have some plugin that blocks standard search loop?

Comment: Hi, something important I have not mentioned is that I am running a custom Wordpress theme, in which there is an option to display blog results but not page results. That would required customizations, and this is beyond my scope.